# Random Forest feature importance showing variable of all zero's halfway up the list

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I have run a random forest regressor on some data with 10000 rows and about 700 variables using the following code

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1000, max_depth=20)
model.fit(X_train, y_train[:,0])
```

One of my variables contains all zeros and yet it is showing up about halfway when I look at an ordered list of

```
model.feature_importances_
```

How can a random forest be using a column that contains zero's for every data point more than other columns that aren't static?

Comment: there are some reasons, what is your output of the regressor? maybe he is always predicting the same value..

Comment: the regressor is predicting different values

Comment: are you sure it is ordered? just to plot: model.feature_importances_ will give you an output which reflects the order of your columns, but not of importances